# SQL: How to union polygon geometries from a single table that have the same id and certain type?

Tags: qgis, sql

Essentially, the table looks like this (geometries are mostly unique, and shouldn't overlap, but may overlap a little):

```
id         sub-id    type         Geometry

123456     1         ordinary     POLYGON(..) 

123456     2         ordinary     POLYGON(..)

123456     3         shoulder     POLYGON(..)

456789     1         shoulder     POLYGON(..)

456789     2         ordinary     POLYGON(..)

456789     3         ordinary     POLYGON(..)

456789     4         ordinary     POLYGON(..)
```

The `ST_union` should combine polygons from rows 1 and 2 (they share same id and have certain desired type: ordinary. I don't care about other types).

Then, it should keep going and the same `ST_Union` should combine polygons from the last three rows shown (again, they share same id and have certain desired type: ordinary. I don't care about other types).

The code would then do an analysis using those aggregate polygons like, say, finding if there is an intersection.

There are perhaps hundreds of thousands of sub-ids so I'm hoping that merging the geometries of the sub-ids (by id and the 'ordinary' type) and then running the intersection analysis later in the code will make increase the efficiency of the query.

I don't want to/shouldn't change the original database, and I can't create a new database or table to be saved on the server.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the 5-minute [Tour],  which explains how our "Focused question/Best answer" model operates. Please [Edit] the question to specify the RDBMS in use and provide the SQL you have written so far.

Comment: So ... where are u stuck at ?

Comment: You can't improve that way, and you shouldn't try to that way, in most cases; if you have nowhere to save and prepare the result set, there is no way to get a spatial index in place. And a spatial index will have significant positive impact on performance when applied on smaller geometries instead! Rather see to the maintenance of your table and **make sure proper (spatial) indexes are in place**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a virtual layer, which keeps the result in memory, and that you could use in your analysis.

go to the menu `layer / add layer / add-edit virtual layer` and use the following query:

```
SELECT id, type, ST_UNION(geometry) as geometry
FROM myLayer
GROUP BY id, type;
```

PS: while it is understandable that you can't write new layer on a server, you should be able to do so locally. It would greatly simplify your workflow...

Comment: this did what I was wondering about. Thank you.

Comment: But how would you then use those many Union'ed geometries and find where those geometries may intersect other geometries in those Union'ed geometries?